# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel really slow

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am exporting a 1200 X 800 matrix (indexMatrix) to a excel file using the standard Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. The app works, just that it is really really really slow( even for the 100 x 100 matrix) . I also export in a text file through a TextWriter an it works almost instantly . Is there any way to export to the excel file faster?

Here is my code :

```
        Excel.Application xlApp=new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        //xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++)   //h
            for (int j = 0; j < 1200; j++)
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i+1,j+1] =indexMatrix[i][j];


        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\a.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\csharp-Excel.xls");
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You are updating individual cells.  That's going to be very slow.  If you think about it, each time you update a cell, an RPC call will be marshalled to the Excel process.

It will be **much** faster if you assign your two dimensional array of values to an Excel Range of the same dimensions in a single statement (one cross-process call) instead of your current 1200 x 800 = 960,000 cross-process calls.

Something like:

```
// Get dimensions of the 2-d array
int rowCount = indexMatrix.GetLength(0);
int columnCount = indexMatrix.GetLength(1);
// Get an Excel Range of the same dimensions
Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range) xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,1];
range = range.get_Resize(rowCount, columnCount);
// Assign the 2-d array to the Excel Range
range.set_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, indexMatrix);
```

Actually, to be pedantic, there are three cross-process calls in the above code (.Cells, .get_Resize and .set_Value), and there are two calls per iteration in your code (.Cells get and an implicit .set_Value) for a total of 1200 x 800 x 2 = 1,920,000.

**Note**
`range.get_Resize` and `range.set_Value` were needed for an old version of the Excel interop library I was using when this post was first authored.  These days you can use `range.Resize` and `range.Value` as noted in the comment by @The1nk.

Comment: there seems to be a problem at .get_Resize . It seems to not exist.

Comment: at excel.range line , the following error appears ''System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'get_Resize''

Comment: I think the edit will fix it.  Cells[1,1] does not return a Range object - so it needs to be cast.

Comment: sorry to bother you again but i got another error : at range.set_value line appeared the error : " SafeArrayTypeMismatchException : Specified array was not of the expected type."

Comment: Your code doesn't show what type it is.  It should be an object array, i.e. object[,]

Comment: You'll need to copy the data from your jagged array (int[][]) to a rectangular array: object[,] or maybe int[,] would work too.

Comment: Beautiful solution, worked tremendously for my 44,279 cells. From 5 minutes to 3 seconds. One note for future visitors - You don't need to use `get_Resize` or `set_Value`. You just use `cell.Resize` and `cell.Value` as normal.

Comment: "If you think about it, each time you update a cell, an RPC call will be marshalled to the Excel process." That will probably still happen even if you don't think about it.

Comment: @The1nk I got similar results. It's amazing how much a simple change can affect performance!

Comment: Thanks, but gives `HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` exception.

Comment: How would I do this if I'm working with objects instead of an array?  Or even better, a List<> of objects?   My objects have multiple property types (string, double, DateTime).

Comment: @Smitty-Werben-Jager-Manjenson did you get any solution about how to use this with List<> of objects?

Comment: @Oxygen, I don't have access to my old code anymore but if I recall, I converted my lists to arrays.

Answer (score 16):

Excel interop is never going to be fast. You're basically remote-controlling an instance of the Excel application. You might have more success by creating a CSV file and then using Excel interop to convert this to a .xls or .xlsx file

Comment: +1 Nice approach, and this ensures to be faster as well, as a CSV file is more likely a text file, so that `TextWriter` class can handle it.

Comment: Yup, that's my preferred method as well. Although you run into problems when cell values contain newlines, as that screws up your row index. Anyone have any tips for this issue?

Comment: In reply to my above comment: use import-csv (powershell) or an equivalent library function that will handle the messy situations with qualifier chars and newlines used in field values.

Answer (score 14):

I had similar problems when reading an extremely large excel file and it took over 2 hours using interop.

I tried using ClosedXml and the process took less than 10 seconds.
[ClosedXml](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

```
// To loop 
Sheet.Row(y).Cell(x).Value
```

Also keep in mind interop will not work on your server unless you have excel installed. ClosedXml does not need excel installed.

Comment: First time to use ClosedXML and it's REALLY fast. I used InsertData with an array of arrays and an argument. Very smooth compared to HSSF and HSSF craziness of POI and the COM Exceptions of interop!!! +1

Comment: ClosedXML is faster because it uses OpenXML, which means it is writing the file directly. There are no intermediate APIs, no UI to update, etc. If it is an option for your use case(s), it is probably always going to be the fastest option, and you could do the same with just normal OpenXML.

Comment: My 2 cents. Using Interop: 39 seconds, using ClosedXml: 0.7 seconds.

Answer (score 7):

Turn off `ScreenUpdating` before writing any data, `Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE` then turn on at end of code `= TRUE`

Answer (score 2):

Use Value2 to make it fast;
Show excel before filling data

Answer (score 2):

**ClosedXML** is a miracle, it's a great deal faster and easier to use.

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();//create the new book

var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Computer Install");// Add a sheet
worksheet.Cell(1,1).Value = "PC Name";// (Row, column) write to a cell

workbook.SaveAs(@"LIC documents.xlsx");// Save the book
```

You install using a nu Get package. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML

Comment: Yup, it is impressive. Went from about 4.5 hours to 5 minutes. Github: https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml

Comment: ClosedXML is faster because it uses OpenXML, which means it is writing the file directly. There are no intermediate APIs, no UI to update, etc. If it is an option for your use case(s), it is probably always going to be the fastest option, and you could do the same with just normal OpenXML.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering a little bit late sorry. I was working on my project and we had to use interop excel. And our data was too big, which was taking more than 1 minute with interop excel. We tried something else which is copy the all content of datagridview to clipboard, open an excel worksheet using interop excel, and paste the content to excel. It takes less than 1 second and exports our data perfectly.

DataGridView to string:

```
    var newline = System.Environment.NewLine;
    var tab = "\t";
    var clipboard_string = "";

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgProjeler.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == (row.Cells.Count - 1))
                clipboard_string += row.Cells[i].Value + newline;
            else
                clipboard_string += row.Cells[i].Value + tab;
        }
    }
```

and copy the string to clipboard

```
        Clipboard.SetText(clipboard_string);
```

And open a worksheet, paste the content.

```
        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
        app.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
        Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
        // changing the name of active sheet
        ws.Name = "Exported from gridview";

        ws.Rows.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        app.ActiveWindow.Activate();


        ws.Activate();
        ws.Paste();

        ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```

It works perfectly on me, I hope it helps people who still couldn't find the solution.

Comment: I was able to forgo the app.Visible, app.ActiveWindow.Activate(), and ws.Activate() and it still worked perfectly on my tab- and newline-delimited string.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do this, 2 of which are mentioned in different answers by others:

1. Directly set the value of a range in excel to the 2D array.
2. Write data to a CSV file, then use interop to save the CSV file as an xls or xlsx file.
3. Write data to a CSV file, then use the data connections feature to use the CSV as a data source and import the data.

All the three methods above are very fast. I could write data with a size of 90000 rows and 100 columns in around 6 seconds.

P.S. They didn't however solve my problem with formatting the data for borders, font styles, colors, cell merging etc.