# Parallel.Foreach on Excel.Range c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I am writing a c# application that reads an Excel file and creates in-memory objects against each row found in the Excel worksheet. I have successfully done this using `for-loop` but would like to use `Parallel.Foreach` to improve the performance since the Excel file contains over 90,000+ records.

I have previously used `Parallel.Foreach` on `DataTable` objects, is there any way I can use it on `Excel.Range` object? I need to iterate on excel data row by row.

Any examples would help.

Comment: Are you sure parallel processing will help here? Have you profiled the time it takes to create your objects? The bottleneck may just be disk access.

Comment: For Excel performance check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17021537/1069200) out. I don't think Parallel.Foreach is going to do anything. Batch-read and then read from memory imo.

Comment: All you need is an IEnumerable<Something>. Your Excel library can probably give you that. Study the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I defined this method which takes Excel.Range object and transform it into lists using PLINQ

```
private List<List<String>> ExcelRangeToLists(Excel.Range cells)
{
   return cells.Rows.Cast<Excel.Range>().AsParallel().Select(row =>
   {         
      return row.Cells.Cast<Excel.Range>().Select(cell =>
      {
         var cellContent = cell.Value2;
         return (cellContent == null) ? String.Empty : cellContent.ToString();                        
      }).Cast<string>().ToList();                
   }).ToList();
});
```

Then, just read some range from excel sheet and call this method

```
var cells = xlSheet.get_Range("A3", "BK1555");
var data = ExcelRangeToLists(cells);
```

Measuring the performance, it is better but not drastically - For example ~20% faster for 1400 rows range (should be even better for larger sets).

I didn't used the Parallel.Foreach since I needed the select to create the lists, but the basic casting idea is similar.

```
Parallel.ForEach(cells.Rows.Cast<Excel.Range>(), row => DoSomethingWithRow(row));
```

Enjoy